gitlab CI/CD pipeline will not run stage "deploy"
I have a gitlab project here:
gitlab_project
and run successfully a CI pipeline for stages "build" and "test" in my gitlab-ci.yml, which is as follows:
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true'
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: '--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true'

# For other maven/openjdk versions see: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/
image: maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

build:openjdk17:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

.verify: &verify
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify'
verify:openjdk17:
  <<: *verify

deploy:openjdk17:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean javafx:jlink com.coderplus.maven.plugins:copy-rename-maven-plugin:1.0:copy'
  only:
    - master


But stage "deploy" will not execute! How do I automatically execute stage "deploy", too?
Thanks in advance!
I expected all three stages to execute: build, test and deploy
but the last one is skipped and not even mentioned by the log.
This is the build job:
build_log
and this is the test job:
verify_log

Can you please share the logs?

edited the OP with logs

Why separated compile and verify .... verify will also run the life cycle phases including compile another time...
Why using TLSv1.2. ? And such an old Maven version?  (3.9.X) https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

removed compile, updated TLSv1.3. Docker + maven + openjdk17 has no later maven version than that.

I checked you repository and I can't find any branch named master, you should probably replace master with main in your gitlab-ci.yml.
